# How can I monitor SQL activity on Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I'd like to find a tool for Oracle that is similar to the SQL Server Profiler, but a cursory search hasn't yielded any good results. I just want to see, in real time, the queries that my application are making against the database.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quest software has some really good tools for Oracle. I think that both [Foglight Performance Analysis for Oracle](http://www.quest.com/Foglight-Performance-Analysis-for-Oracle/) and [Spotlight](http://www.quest.com/spotlight-on-oracle/) do what you're looking for. Not sure for Spotlight though.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'm downloading the demos now to see if they are what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5):

The v$ views in Oracle (which a lot of tools use) offer a wealth of information if you have access to them.

Here's an [example](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:497421739750) on askTom to find the sql the current users are executing.

Comment: I do have access to them, but I don't want to have to manually run queries. I'd like some kind of visual tool that updates in real-time.

Comment: TOAD from Quest (as Pascal mentioned) has this functionality

Answer (score 4):

AWR (automatic workload repository) is the most obvious answer. There's a description [here](http://www.oracle.com/technology/pub/articles/10gdba/week6_10gdba.html).

But Oracle Enterprise Manager has better interface. Read about it [here](http://www.oracle.com/enterprise_manager/index.html). You have to pay extra, but it gives you the interactivity you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and links. I have a strong dislike for OEM, but that's probably because I'm fairly new to Oracle and not used to it. :)

Answer (score 2):

PL/SQL Developer from [Allround Automations](http://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html) is what we use here. More geared towards developers, it does have a session browser which will show locks, SQL statements, etc. Also a nice graphical explain plan window. It's cheaper than TOAD (at last look).