# Oracle Query Monitor

Tags: oracle, monitor, oracle11g

i want know querys of third party software executed in my oracle server, anybody know how i can do that?i will use one time, can be trial software or script anything..thx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555535/how-can-i-monitor-sql-activity-on-oracle

Answer (score 1):

orastat - a Unix-based command-line tool (http://dbamon.com/)

view running SQL:

```
orastat -sr SESSION_NUMBER
```