# Another Oracle sql monitoring tool

Tags: sql, session, plsql, monitoring, oracle11g

Probably has been asked before, but i'm looking for a utility, which can

1. Identify a particular session and record all activity.
2. Able to identify the sql that was executed under that session.
3. Identify any stored procedures/functions/packages that were executed.
4. And able to show what was passed as parameters into the procs/funcs.

I'm looking for a IDE thats lightweight, fast, available and won't take 2 day's to install, i.e something I can get down, install and use in the next 1 hour.

Bob.

Comment: perhaps this SO question would help? [How can I monitor SQL activity on Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555535/how-can-i-monitor-sql-activity-on-oracle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of to do this is probably already installed in your database - it's the `DBMS_MONITOR` package, which writes trace files to the location identified by `user_dump_dest`.  As such, you'd need help from someone with access to the database server to access the trace files.

But once, you've identified the `SID` and `SERIAL#` of the session you want to trace, you can just call:

`EXEC dbms_monitor.session_trace_enable (:sid, :serial#, FALSE, TRUE);`

To capture all the SQL statements being run, including the values passed in as binds.

Comment: I used this.                                                                                                                                  select  c.name                     BIND, 
        substr(c.value_string,1,25) VAL
from    v$sqlarea a, 
        v$sql_bind_capture c
where   a.sql_id = c.sql_id 
and     a.hash_value = '3436831386 '
order by a.last_active_time desc, c.name asc
;

Comment: You plug in the hash value for the sql statement and it returns the marshalled bind list.

Answer (score 1):

if you have license for Oracle Diagnostic/Tuning Packs, you may use Oracle Active Session History feature ASH

Comment: More on ASH and "Active Session History Statistics" at http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGDBA/measure_db.htm#TGDBA148